# How to generate Shipment return label from Fedex api

Tags: salesforce, fedex, salesforce-service-cloud

I am planning to integrate fedex api in my salesforce e-commerce project. The requirement is if the customer lost the return label. They will reach out us to generate for them.

Is it possible to retrieve the label information by sending the tracking/order number in the request.

I went through the latest fedex webservice documentation but I couldn't find the exact scenario what I am looking for. I found a section "Print return label" but it looks the API is to create a return shipment in that response I am getting a label.

Please correct me If my understanding is wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey I'm facing a similar issue was wondering if you ever resolved this? @Mangoski

Comment: Yes I am able to figure but not on the same SOAP call because we need to pass so many parameter and it didn't accept null values also for certain field so made it as REST API call

Comment: Hey @Mangoski thanks for the response. Would you mind sharing what your request looked like?